# Migrated question advertised on original site

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

Not really a bug, just amusing...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question migration was reversed and the original EL&U question reopened, so this is just a transient issue until a Parenting mod deletes their question.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm having trouble keeping up! :) It's going to be messy trying to knit the answers/comments back together...

Comment: Ha! The reversal was reversed! I generated a migration war. (`Democracy--`)